# Why is Rademacher complexity defined the way it is?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

For reference, this is the definition of empirical Rademacher complexity from [Foundations of Machine Learning](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/) (page 30):

> Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a family of functions mapping from $\mathcal{Z}$
>   to $[a, b]$, and $S=(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_m)$ a fixed sample of size $m$
>   with elements in $\mathcal{Z}$. Then, the empirical Rademacher
>   complexity of $\mathcal{G}$ with respect to the sample $S$ is defined
>   as: $$
>  \hat{R}_S=\mathbb{E}_{\overrightarrow{\sigma}}\left[\sup_{g\in\mathcal{G}}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sigma_ig(z_i)\right] $$ where
>   $\overrightarrow{\sigma}=[\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_m]^T$, with
>   $\sigma_i$s independent uniform random variables taking values in
>   $\{-1,1\}$. The random variables $\sigma_i$ are called Rademacher
>   variables.

Previously, $\mathcal{G}$ was described, in the context of learning, as a family of functions which map $(x,y)$ to $L(h(x), y)$, with $x$ being an example, $y$ its target value, $h$ a hypothesis from the hypothesis space and $L$ the chosen loss function. **In that regard, wouldn't it make more sense for $\sigma_i$s to be defined over $[a, b]$ in order to have the same range as $g(z)$, rather than $\{-1, 1\}$?**

Since the expression under the supremum measures correlation between the random noise and performance of $h$, does the empirical Rademacher complexity tell us how well a hypothesis space can fit the given sample **to an arbitrary level of performance**?